# Zend_AMF endpoint protection in a Flash Game deployed in Facebook

Tags: flash, zend-framework, amf

can anyone think of a feasable protection of my Zend_AMF gateway? I mean, how can I prevent someone from calling my service methods?

Thanks in advance!
teebee

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but looks like you could start a secure session in your bootstrap with [Zend_Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html). Here's a good post from Wade Arnold that gives an example - http://wadearnold.com/blog/flash/zend-amf-now-with-php-session-support.